# The javascript function for a form control doesn't work, it doesn't read the statement if where there is a >

Tags: javascript

html

```
<html>
    <header>
    </header>
    <body>
        <form name="acquista" id="registration-form">
            User name
            <input name="user"><br>
            E-mail
            <input name="email"><br>
            Password
            <input name="psw"><br>
            <input id="quantitaAcquisto" type="hidden" name="quantitaAcquisto" value="100">
            quantita
            <input id="quantita" type="number" name="quantita" onkeyup="validateQuantita()"><br>
            <span id="quantitaControl"></span>
            <input type="submit" value="Validate">
        </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
function validateQuantita(){
    var quantita = document.getElementById('quantita').value;
    var quantitaAcquisto = document.getElementById('quantitaAcquisto').value;
    var span = document.getElementById('quantitaControl');
    document.acquista.quantita.style.color='#000000';
    span.innerHTML = "";
    if (quantita > quantitaAcquisto){
        document.acquista.quantita.style.color='red';
        span.innerHTMl = "non hai abbastanza azioni";
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a check on the quantity, if the quantity is greater than the amount of purchase i should color the red input text and insert the text into the span, but it does not work.

Comment: Those are strings.

Comment: A [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) would be helpful.

Comment: "should color the red input text … but it does not work" — It seems to go red when I test it. Clear problem statements make debugging easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
span.innerHTMl = ...
```

to

```
span.innerHTML = ...
```

and change

```
if (quantita > quantitaAcquisto){
```

to

```
if (quantita > parseInt(quantitaAcquisto, 10)){
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the innerHTML typo, it is not l but L, all capital.
And parse the string values to int, so the comparison works.

This runs the way you expect it:

```
<html>
<header>
</header>
<body>
<form name="acquista" id="registration-form">
  User name
  <input name="user"><br>
  E-mail
  <input name="email"><br>
  Password
  <input name="psw"><br>
  <input id="quantitaAcquisto" type="hidden" name="quantitaAcquisto" value="100">
  quantita
  <input id="quantita" type="number" name="quantita" onkeyup="validateQuantita()"><br>
  <span id="quantitaControl"></span>
  <input type="submit" value="Validate">
</form>
<script>
  function validateQuantita() {
    var quantita = document.getElementById('quantita').value;
    var quantitaAcquisto = document.getElementById('quantitaAcquisto').value;
    var span = document.getElementById('quantitaControl');
    document.acquista.quantita.style.color = '#000000';
    span.innerHTML = '';
    if (parseInt(quantita, 10) > parseInt(quantitaAcquisto, 10)) {
      document.acquista.quantita.style.color = 'red';
      span.innerHTML = 'non hai abbastanza azioni';
    }
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/zoxugizuke/edit?html,output